# Simple XQuery Not Working Due to Namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, xml-namespaces

I have an xml document as such:

```
<ns0:Employee xmlns:ns0="http://namespace">
  <EmployeeID></EmployeeID>
  <Department></Department>
  <FirstName> </FirstName>
  <MiddleInitial />
  <LastName></LastName>
  <IsActive></IsActive>
  <CreateDate>2017-07-25T14:18:14.513</CreateDate>
  <UpdateDate>2018-01-25T16:58:52.733</UpdateDate>
  <PrimaryRole></PrimaryRole>
  <TempPassword></TempPassword>
  <License></License>
  <AccessLevelID></AccessLevelID>
  <CompanyID></CompanyID>
  <Schedule></Schedule>
</ns0:Employee>
```

and am attempting to get the CreateDate and UpdateDates out of it. I've tried the following:

```
select
  [xmlcolumn].value('(/Employee/CreateDate)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as CreateDate
from
  table
```

But this is always returning a null value, despite there being a CreateDate. If I remove the namespace from the xml document, my query returns the CreateDate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query doesn't include the namespace.  You can do this to include the namespace:

```
select
  [xmlcolumn].value('declare namespace ns0="http://namespace";(/ns0:Employee/CreateDate)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as CreateDate
from
  table
```

Or just use this

```
select
  [xmlcolumn].value('(/*/CreateDate)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as CreateDate
from
  table
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks.